# Pseudo command :[line number][eof]d

Tags: key-bindings

How could I execute the entitled command, as is (I give a pseudo version)? My current workaround is to `G` to get the eof line number itself, then execute the command.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Do you want to delete the last line of the buffer? You can do that with `:$d`, with `$` meaning the last line. Do you want to delete from the current line to the end? Then you can use `:.,$d`. From line 10 to the end? `:10,$d`. Please [edit] the question to make it clear what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `:10,$d` was what I was referring to. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete from line 10 to the end of the file, you can use:

```
:10,$d
```

(Assuming the first line in the range is line 10, adjust for a different numbered line.)

The `$` address means the last line in the current buffer. See [`:help :range`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) for other valid addresses in a range.